# Refer to an overlapping function with "using namespace std"

Tags: c++

I am well aware of pitfalls by doing this. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

using namespace std;

//a simple function that returns the index of max and max value of a parameter pack
template <typename...T>
tuple<int, int> max(T... args) 
{
  const int size = sizeof...(args);
  int list[size] = {args...};

  int max_i = 0;
  int max = list[0];

  for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
      if (list[i] > max)
        {
          max_i = i;
          max = list[i];
        }
    }  
  return std::tuple<int, int>{max_i, max};
}

int main()
{
  int a ,b;
  tie(a, b) = max(10, 20, 30);

  return 0;
}
```

My function gets a lower priority with that of `std::max` and produces an error. I want to know if there is a way to still refer to my `max` function whilst declaring `using namespace std;`. You needn't remind me not to declare it.

Comment: I need to remind you to not declare it because you've declared it.

Comment: @eerorika Where is this documented? Is that because of C?

Comment: @underscore_d I thought it was. But it turns out that C doesn't have `max`. It has `fmax`. So, declaring `::max` is OK. I would still advocate declaring everything in a namespace in real projects.

Comment: @eerorika I guess that otherwise the relevant part of the standard is that [\[extern.names\]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/extern.names#3) would apply?

Comment: @dfri Yes, and also /4.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can invoke your particular `max` overload using the scope resolution operator `::` to ensure qualified name lookup is performed instead of unqualified one:

```
::max(10, 20, 30);
```

in which case overload resolution will consider your own `max` function overload as a *better viable function* than that that of the overload in the `std` namespace. From [cppreference - Qualified lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/qualified_lookup) [**emphasis** mine]:

> #### Namespace members
>
> [...]
>
> Qualified lookup within the scope of a namespace `N` **first considers
> all declarations that are located in `N`** and all declarations that
> are located in the inline namespace members of `N` (and, transitively,
> in their inline namespace members). If there are no declarations in
> that set **then it considers declarations in all namespaces named by
> using-directives** found in `N` and in all transitive inline namespace
> members of `N`. [...]